# Laravel avoid duplicate entry from model

Tags: laravel

I'm building a Laravel API. I have a models called `Reservations`. I want to avoid that a user creates two reservations for the same product and time period.

I have the following:

```
$reservation =  Reservation::firstOrCreate([
   'listing_id'    =>  $request->listing_id,
   'user_id_from'  =>  $request->user_id_from,
   'start_date'    =>  $request->start_date,
   'end_date'      =>  $request->end_date,
]);
```

**Edit after comments:**

I'm also using validation

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'listing_id'    =>  'required|exists:listings,id',
            'user_id_from'  =>  'required|exists:users,id',
            'start_date'    =>  'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:today',
            'end_date'      =>  'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:start_date'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Validation failed'], 403);
        }
```

Validation is working properly.

**End of Edit**

In my model I have casted the start_date and end_date as `dates`.

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['listing_id', 'start_date', 'end_date'];
    protected $dates = [
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];
    ....
    ....
```

Documentation says:

> The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record
>   using the given column / value pairs

However I notice that I'm still able to insert entries with the same attributes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a better way than this, but you can create an static method on Reservation to do this, like:

```
public static function createWithRules($data) {
    $exists = $this->where('product_id', $data['product_id'])->whereBetween(*date logic that i don't remember right now*)->first();

    if(!$exists) {
        * insert logic *
    } else {
        * product with date exists *
    }

}
```

So you can call Reservation::createWithRules($data)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Laravel's built in `ValidateRequest` class. The most simple use-case for this validation, is to call it directly in your `store()` method like this:

```
public function store(){

   $this->validate($request, [
      'listing_id' => 'required|unique,
      'start_date' => 'required|unique,
      //... and so on
   ], $this->messages);

   $reservation =  Reservation::firstOrCreate([
      'listing_id'    =>  $request->listing_id,
      'user_id_from'  =>  $request->user_id_from,
      'start_date'    =>  $request->start_date,
      'end_date'      =>  $request->end_date,
   ]);
}
```

With this, you're validating users `$request` with by saying that specified columns are `required` and that they need to be `unique`, in order for validation to pass. 
In your controller, you can also create messages function to display error messages, if the condition isn't met.

```
private $messages = [
      'listing_id.required' =>  'Listing_id is required',
      'title.unique' => 'Listing_id already exists',
      //... and so on 

    ];
```

You can also achieve this by creating a new custom validation class:

```
php artisan make:request StoreReservation
```

The generated class will be placed in the `app/Http/Requests` directory. Now, you can add a few validation rules to the rules method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'listing_id' => 'required|unique,
      'start_date' => 'required|unique,
      //... and so on
    ];
}
```

All you need to do now is type-hint the request on your controller method. The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called, meaning you do not need to clutter your controller with any validation logic:

```
public function store(StoreReservation $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...

    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

If you have any additional question about this, feel free to ask. Source: Laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation).

Comment: The OP stated that he wants to avoid that a user creates two reservations for the same product and time period. I provided my solution by using Laravel's built in request validation. Is there something wrong with my code? @VincentDecaux

Comment: @zlatangoralija Sorry for the confusion. I'm using validation already, I edited the original post. I understand your suggestion to use the 'unique' parameter in the validation, but this is just avoiding I use for instance a duplicate listng_id (which is allowed). It is the combination of the listing_id, the start_date and the end_date that should not be duplicate. Therefore I was hoping to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods