# Laravel: avoid duplicate entries in database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel API. I have a models called Reservations. I want to avoid that a user creates two reservations for the same product and time period.

I have the following:

```
$reservation =  Reservation::firstOrCreate([
   'listing_id'    =>  $request->listing_id,
   'user_id_from'  =>  $request->user_id_from,
   'start_date'    =>  $request->start_date,
   'end_date'      =>  $request->end_date,
]);
return new ReservationResource($reservation);
```

Documentation says:

> The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record
>   using the given column / value pairs

The above code is working:

- it does add the item to the database if it does not exist yet (in
  this case, the reply to the REST API returns the new model instance
  which is correct.
- it does not add the item to the database if the combination equals `listing_id, user_id_from, start_date and end_date`.

However, in the latter case (item already exists), it will also return in the REST API reply a reservation with the ID of the matched row.

Example: in the below table, reservation with id 2 already exists:

```
id  listing_id  user_id_from    start_date  end_date
------------------------------------------------------  
1      2            3               2019-09-12  2019-10-14
```

Sending the below REST API request:

```
{
    "listing_id": 2,
    "user_id_from": 3,
    "start_date": "2019-09-12",
    "end_date": "2019-10-14",
}
```

returns

```
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id_from": 3,
    "listing_id": 2,
    "price": 388,
    "start_date": "2019-09-12",
    "end_date": "2019-10-14",
 }
```

I would want to have a JSON reply stating that the item already exists. How can this be achieved?

Comment: a user cannot double book (no time constraints), or are you just trying to avoid multiple form submission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel avoid duplicate entry from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597660/laravel-avoid-duplicate-entry-from-model) from the same user

Answer (score 1):

[`firstOrCreate()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L217) is just a two-part function as you might expect, doing a lookup on `first()` and falling back to `create()` if not exists.  You could implement much the same logic in your controller, and append a message to the `first()` result if it exists, and return the result as-is if created.  Alternatively, you could modify the response with a `HTTP_OK` or `HTTP_CREATED` depending on the result.  Or both.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = [
        'listing_id' => $request->input('listing_id'), 
        'user_id_from' => $request->input('user_id_from'), 
        'start_date' => $request->input('start_date'),
        'end_date' => $request->input('end_date')
    ];

    // return existing reservation if exists
    $reservation = Reservation::where($attributes)->first();

    if ($reservation !== null) {
        // add explicit message here if you want
        return response(json_encode($reservation), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    // else create a new one
    $reservation = Reservation::create($attributes);

    // reload model
    $reservation = Reservation::find($reservation->id);

    return response(json_encode($reservation), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Laravel's `wasRecentlyCreated`:

```
if(! $reservation->wasRecentlyCreated){ 
      // create & encode a JSON response  or use this variable & method on the blade page
}
```